# The manifest has invalid search provider url which is not owned by the developer - chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension which overrides the chrome settings. And for instance I am overriding the default search engine to my own custom search engine.

While testing it locally it works great, but when I tried to upload it, it gives me the following errors.

```js
The manifest has an invalid homepage url that is not owned by the developer:
https://www.my-search.com/.

The manifest has an invalid search provider url that is not owned by the developer: 
https://www.my-search.com/search?aid=4898&zoneid=89111407&q={searchTerms}.


Upload
Win Free Gifts
Short name: Win Free Gifts
Version 1.0 by aloni.rozi

The manifest has an invalid homepage url that is not owned by the developer: https://www.my-search.com/.

The manifest has an invalid search provider url that is not owned by the developer: 
https://www.my-search.com/search?aid=4898&zoneid=89111407&q={searchTerms}.
```

Below is my `manifest.json` file :

```js
{
 "name":"Win Free Gifts",
 "short_name": "Win Free Gifts",
 "author" : "Nadeem Ahmad",
 "description":"Win 1000's of gifts every day ! ",
 "version":"1.0",
 "manifest_version":2,
 "icons":{
  "16":"icons/job_icon.png",
  "32":"icons/job_icon.png",
  "64":"icons/job_icon.png"
 },
 "browser_action":{
  "default_icon":"icons/job_icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
 
 "chrome_url_overrides" : {
     "newtab": "show.html"
 },

 "chrome_settings_overrides": {
     "homepage": "https://www.my-search.com/",
  "search_provider": {
         "name": "Nadeem Ahmad",
         "keyword": "keyword.__MSG_url_domain__",
         "search_url": "https://www.my-search.com/search?aid=4898&zoneid=89111407&q={searchTerms}",
         "alternate_urls": [
           "https://www.my-search.com/search?aid=4898&zoneid=89111407&q={searchTerms}",
           "https://www.my-search.com/search?aid=4898&zoneid=89111407&q={searchTerms}"
         ],
         "encoding": "UTF-8",
         "is_default": true
     }
 },


 "permissions":[
        "cookies",
  "tabs",
  "notifications",
        "<all_urls>"
 ]
}
```

Comment: Have you verified the domain `www.my-search.com` as yours in the developer's dashboard?

Comment: On the hosting? @IvánNokonoko

Comment: Can you link me there ? how can i verify it @wOxxOm

Comment: [Developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to verify the search provider website (in your case, `https://www.my-search.com`) in the [Developer's Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard).

According to the [documentation for Settings Overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override):

> Web sites used in the settings API must be verified (via Webmaster
> Tools) as being associated with that item in the Chrome Web Store.
> Note that if you verify ownership for a domain (for example,
> http://example.com) you can use any subdomain or page (for example,
> http://app.example.com or http://example.com/page.html) within your
> extension

This is also critical (thanks to @mlissner):

You **must be a website owner**. If you have another account that already "owns" the domain in Webmaster Tools, you can add a second owner. Having "Full" access is not enough.

Comment: Note that you must be a website *owner*. If you have another account that already "owns" the domain in Webmaster Tools, you can add a second owner. Having "Full" access is not enough. There's a specific page for this in Webmaster Tools, but the URL sucks so I can't share it. Basically though, you need to go to the Users and Permissions page, and then it should have a link next to the current Owner that allows you to add more owners. Oof, this took me a while.

Comment: could you explain where in the developer dashboard?

Comment: @Antonio In Developer Dashboard - Store Listing - Additional fields or in Google Search Console.

Comment: @mlissner thanks for your comment. That was my missing part. I've added it to the response above